# How many days does monitoring in LEX service will retain logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

There is a monitoring feature in `lex`service.

We can see user utterances which are passed and failed, From there we can even add the failed utterances to intent but I couldn't find any information on how many days logged utterances will be retained.

Can someone provide information about that?